# Unable to build expo project on Xcode 14.3 [Operation not permitted]

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo, cocoapods

I successfully built a basic Expo project with Xcode (only App.js, no packages, no screens). Now, I'm attempting to create a project with multiple screens and the following packages:

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
"expo": "~49.0.15",
"expo-linear-gradient": "^12.5.0",
"expo-modules-autolinking": "^1.5.1",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
"expo-system-ui": "~2.4.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.6",
"react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^3.0.7",
"react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
"react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
"react-native-progress": "^5.0.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
"react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
"react-native-webview": "^13.6.3"
```

However, when I follow the same steps I used for the basic project, such as:

```
npm install
npx expo run:ios
cd ios
pod install
```

And then open the project in Xcode, I encounter the following build error:

```
/bin/bash: /Users/[USER]/Documents/GitHub/[PROJECT]/ios/Pods/../../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/../scripts/xcode/with-environment.sh: Operation not permitted

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I've attempted to change the permissions of the with-environment.sh file and open Xcode with root, but nothing seems to work. Could this be related to a specific package causing the issue? Any help would be appreciated.

```
[USER]@MacBook-2 ios % npx -v
9.8.1
[USER]@MacBook-2 ios % npx expo -v
0.10.16
[USER]@MacBook-2 ios % node -v          
v18.18.0
```

I tried to change permissions, it expected to build successfully, it built with problems

Comment: It's just a guess but can you remove the Pods and reinstall via ```npx pod-install``` from app folder.

Comment: I tried, but I still can't make it work